# How to read value from Response header in mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I am unable to get value from the response header in MVC Controller. I have azure function HTTP triggered and trying to pass the value to the response header "ClientIPADDR: MYCustomHeaders" with 302 redirects. So how do read the value from the response header in the MVC controller?

```
 Cache-Control:no-cache
    ClientIPADDR:MYCustomHeaders
    Content-Length:0
    Date:Mon, 22 Jan 2018 14:03:09 GMT
    Expires:-1
    Location:http://example-read-response-header.azurewebsites.net/home/index
    Pragma:no-cache
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

var ipAddress= Request.Headers["ClientIPADDR"];

Request.ServerVariables.Get("ClientIPADDR");

tried with this but was not able to get the value.

**Edit: With additional information**

Here is an azure function which will do 302 redirect with the given URL which will show the HTML page with google captcha page with **azure function proxy**

```
    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "testExample/{token}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string token, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string ipAddress = string.Empty;
        if (req.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
        {
            ipAddress = ((HttpContextWrapper)req.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        HttpResponseMessage errorResponse;
        errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
        errorResponse.Headers.Add("ClientIPAddress", ipAddress);
        errorResponse.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://localhost:62418/Home/Index" + "?code=" + token);
        return errorResponse;
    }
```

This function displays a captcha HTML page with the azure proxy route to form action attribute which will redirect to the controller action method I am trying to get the client IP address but it is giving me the azure app service IP address.

```
<form name="ad" id="form1" action="/validate" method="post">
        <main class="main-padding">
           //google captcha html
            </div>
        </main>
    </form>
```

without using proxy

```
<form name="ad" id="form1" action="http://example-read-response-header.azurewebsites.net/home/index" method="post">
            <main class="main-padding">
               //google captcha html
                </div>
            </main>
        </form>
```

The above POST method gives the correct IP address. If I do not want to show azure's website URL in HTML and going with proxy usage gives me azure app service URL. I tried passing client IP address in headers but the controller action method is not getting that that header(Request. Header["ClientIPAddress"]). Is there any other way to get the Client's IP Address?

Comment: Try to use `Response.Headers["ClientIPADDR"]`.

Comment: tried Response.Headers["ClientIPADDR"], coming null value.

Comment: Try using this: `Response.Headers.AllKeys.Any(x => string.Equals(x, "ClientIPADDR"))` and see if it contains certain value.